# Archiving mail in a smart mailbox in macOS Apple Mail doesn't work

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I'm using Apple Mail on macOS 10.14.6. I have multiple IMAP mail accounts set up in it including a Gmail account, and combine some of the mail together using smart mailboxes.

In one of these smart mailboxes, I try to archive mail from my Gmail account and it's not working. All of my other mail accounts behave correctly when archiving their mail from this smart mailbox, but for some reason my Gmail account does not. If I archive my Gmail account's mail in its actual mailbox and not the smart mailbox, it works correctly.

Is there anything I can do to fix this or work around it? Not being able to archive mail from a smart mailbox would be a dealbreaker for me.